# fill_between does not fill in the correct portion

Tags: matplotlib

I created a planck's curve with spectral colour for visible light range.

problem:
I would like to create a shading area under the curve. But I failed to to color the correct area under the curve. Thank you very much.

I tried:

1.
`plt.fill_between(wavelengths,0,spectrum, color='w')`,
but this does not work.
2. I also tried
`plt.fill_between(wavelengths,1e13-spectrum, color='w')`
again this does not work

[image: planck curve]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
    
h = 6.626e-34
c = 3.0e+8
k = 1.38e-23

def planck(wav, T):
    a = 2.0*h*c**2
    wav = wav*1e-9
    b = h*c/(wav*k*T)
    intensity = a/ ( (wav**5) * (np.exp(b) - 1.0) )
    return intensity

def wavelength_to_rgb(wavelength, gamma=0.8):

    '''taken from http://www.noah.org/wiki/Wavelength_to_RGB_in_Python
    This converts a given wavelength of light to an 
    approximate RGB color value. The wavelength must be given
    in nanometers in the range from 380 nm through 750 nm
    (789 THz through 400 THz).

    Based on code by Dan Bruton
    http://www.physics.sfasu.edu/astro/color/spectra.html
    Additionally alpha value set to 0.5 outside range'''

    wavelength = float(wavelength)
    if wavelength >= 380 and wavelength <= 750:
        A = 1.
    else:
        A=0.5
    if wavelength < 380:
        wavelength = 380.
    if wavelength >750:
        wavelength = 750.
    if wavelength >= 380 and wavelength <= 440:
        attenuation = 0.3 + 0.7 * (wavelength - 380) / (440 - 380)
        R = ((-(wavelength - 440) / (440 - 380)) * attenuation) ** gamma
        G = 0.0
        B = (1.0 * attenuation) ** gamma
    elif wavelength >= 440 and wavelength <= 490:
        R = 0.0
        G = ((wavelength - 440) / (490 - 440)) ** gamma
        B = 1.0
    elif wavelength >= 490 and wavelength <= 510:
        R = 0.0
        G = 1.0
        B = (-(wavelength - 510) / (510 - 490)) ** gamma
    elif wavelength >= 510 and wavelength <= 580:
        R = ((wavelength - 510) / (580 - 510)) ** gamma
        G = 1.0
        B = 0.0
    elif wavelength >= 580 and wavelength <= 645:
        R = 1.0
        G = (-(wavelength - 645) / (645 - 580)) ** gamma
        B = 0.0
    elif wavelength >= 645 and wavelength <= 750:
        attenuation = 0.3 + 0.7 * (750 - wavelength) / (750 - 645)
        R = (1.0 * attenuation) ** gamma
        G = 0.0
        B = 0.0
    else:
        R = 0.0
        G = 0.0
        B = 0.0
    return (R,G,B,A)

clim=(350,780)
norm = plt.Normalize(*clim)
wl = np.arange(clim[0],clim[1]+1,2)
colorlist = list(zip(norm(wl),[wavelength_to_rgb(w) for w in wl]))
spectralmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("spectrum", colorlist)
    
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8,4), tight_layout=True)
    
wavelengths = np.linspace(100, 4000, 1000)
spectrum = planck(wavelengths, 5778)
plt.plot(wavelengths, spectrum, color='darkred')
    
y = np.linspace(0, 3e13, 10)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(wavelengths, y)
    
extent=(np.min(wavelengths), np.max(wavelengths), np.min(y), np.max(y))
    
plt.imshow(X, clim=clim,  extent=extent, cmap=spectralmap, aspect='auto')
plt.xticks(fontsize =15)
plt.xlabel('Wavelength (nm)',fontsize =20)
    
plt.title('Shortwave radiation',fontsize =20)
plt.text(1000,2.5e13, 'Sun 5778K',fontsize =20)
plt.fill_between(wavelengths,0,spectrum, color='w')
plt.savefig('WavelengthColors.png', dpi=200)
ax = plt.gca()
#ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
right_side = ax.spines["right"]
right_side.set_visible(False)
left_side = ax.spines["left"]
left_side.set_visible(False)
top_side = ax.spines["top"]
top_side.set_visible(False)
plt.ylabel("Normalized spectral emittance",fontsize =20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The posted image seems to color the area below the curve white. What are you expecting to be different?

Comment: I would like to color the portion above the curve white

Comment: ok I figure it out thanks .'''plt.fill_between(wavelengths,3e13,spectrum, color='w')'''

Comment: Afterwards you might need `plt.ylim(0, 3e13)` because `fill_between` probably will change the shown portion of the y axis.